# Ansible escape a seccession of curly braces

Tags: regex, ansible, jinja2, curly-braces

I'm writing an Ansible playbook to configure network teaming and I have the following jinja2 template file in my playbook:

```
DEVICE=team0
DEVICETYPE=Team
ONBOOT=yes
BOOTPROTO=none
IPADDR="{{ ip }}"
PREFIX="{{ prefix }}"
GATEWAY="{{ gateway }}" 
TEAM_CONFIG='{"runner": {"name": "loadbalance"}, "tx_hash": ["eth", "ipv4"], "ports": {{{ ports_list | join(', ') }}}, "link_watch": {"name": "ethtool"}}'
```

I wanted to know is a there a way to escape the first curly brace of "ports": {{{ ports_list | join(', ') }} as I want Ansible to automatically calculate it to have the following output in the final jinja2 file:

```
"ports": {"ens1": {}, "ens2": {}}
```

N.B: I've already tried {{ ports_list | to_json }} and {{ ports_list | join(', ') | to_json }}

Comment: I don't see any programming here, so I'll go on a limb and say notepad++, search "{{{" replace with "{"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like you are looking for [`to_json`](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_filters.html#filters-for-formatting-data) filter:

```
"ports": {{ ports_list | to_json }}
```

I guess you may want to apply it to whole config object.

Comment: I'm using it, I changed the initial post to include the jinja2 line.

Comment: I don't see any mention of `to_json` there.

Comment: Sorry I pasted the line with no "to_json" but I'm having the same results.

Comment: Thanks a lot Konstantin.